# Binding String Format Number Commas & No Decimal Places

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, string-formatting

Okay this is an easy one but I'd hugely appreciate your help because I've been mucking around for an hour trying to get it to work.

How do I change the following to get rid of the decimal places and just show the whole number?

```
Binding="{Binding ANLA, StringFormat=n}"
```

I know the format is something like

```
{0:0,0}
```

But I can't get the backslashes to work.

Thanks hugely in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *almost* had it... how about trying this:

```
{Binding ANLA, StringFormat='0,0.'}
```

Please note that this *will* round the number to the nearest integer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks heaps Sheridan. You helped me out on another question as well. I really appreciate it.