# String Format Integer With Commas, No Decimal Places and Nothing for 0 Values

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, string-formatting

Okay before I get right into my question does anyone know if there is a tool for building string formats? What I'm thinking is something like a pretty simple user interface where you choose whether you want to display commas, zero values, dollar signs etc and then it spits out the stringformat for you. If there is one I'd love to know about it. If there's not it's the sort of thing people like me would love!

My question is. What is the string format for displaying an integer with comma separators for thousands, no decimal places and nothing for zero values.

I know the string format for an integer with comma separators and no decimal places is:

```
StringFormat='0,0.'
```

And I know the string format for displaying nothing for zero values is:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:#}'
```

But combining the two has me stumped. Thanks very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding String Format Number Commas & No Decimal Places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759229/binding-string-format-number-commas-no-decimal-places)

Comment: @RolandShaw, if you look closely, you'll see that this same dude asked that other question that you linked to... so I'm guessing that it *is* slightly different. Bish, what do you mean by 'nothing for zeros'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but after comparing your two string formats, I *think* I know what you're after... please let me know if I am mistaken.

Once again, you *almost* had what I *think* you want... how about trying this:

```
StringFormat='{}{0:#,#.}'
```

Or just

```
StringFormat='#,#.'  (Just replace the '0' from your example with '#')
```

These are equivalent. Please note that again, these will both round the number to the nearest integer.

UPDATE >>>

Here are two very useful links to help you with your `string.Format`s in the future:

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, thanks heaps Sheridan (again!). If anyone has any recommendations for the best resource on string formats please post. I'll post the best thing I find. PS: what I meant by nothing for zeroes is blank cells when there is a zero value.

Comment: Hey Bish, I looked at your example formats and guessed the rest. I'll add some excellent `string.Format` links to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ContentStringFormat is separate dependency property out side of Bindig{} assets.

```
ContentStringFormat='{}{0:#}'
```

Example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment}" ContentStringFormat="Amount is {0}" />
```